# Comparator type error

Tags: c++, templates, compare

I need to create Index of sorted numbers of vector. And create set of T * compared by diffrent fields.

This dosnt compile: bool Comparator::operator ()(const valType &,const valType &) const:  Cant make type cast from "POI *const " in "const POI &".

POI have 2 fields label(std::string), type(uint)

```
template <typename FieldType, typename valType, FieldType valType::*iMember>
class Comparator
{
public:
    bool operator()(valType const& iLeft, valType const& iRight) const {
        return iLeft->*iMember > iRight->*iMember;
    }
};

template< class ValType, class CompType, typename FieldType >
class SearchIndex
{
public:
    SearchIndex() {}
    void Build( std::vector< ValType > iElems, std::ofstream & oStream )
    {
        std::map< ValType *, size_t > numbersOfElems;

        for( std::vector< ValType >::iterator it = iElems.begin(); it != iElems.end(); ++it){
            m_elems.insert( &(*it));
            numbersOfElems.insert(std::pair< ValType * , size_t>( &(*it),5));
        }

        oStream << m_elems.size();
        for( std::multiset< ValType * >::iterator it = m_elems.begin(); it!= m_elems.end(); ++it )
            oStream << numbersOfElems[*it] << " " ;
    }

private:
    std::multiset< ValType * , CompType > m_elems;
};
```

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector< POI > testVect;

    POI sec( "Gas", 1 );
    testVect.push_back(sec);
    POI th( "Tryy", 3 );
    testVect.push_back(th);

    std::ofstream oStream;
    oStream.open("Index.dat",std::ofstream::app | std::ofstream::binary | std::ofstream::out );

    typedef Comparator<std::string, POI, &POI::m_label> POIbyLabel;

    SearchIndex< POI, POIbyLabel, std::string> testIndex;

    testIndex.Build( testVect, oStream );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

&(*it) is type "POI *" in SearchIndex while the accepting parameter of Comparator is "const POI"(valType const&); try to use m_elems.insert(*it);

Comment: This does not helps. std::multiset< ValType * , CompType > m_elems;

Comment: Sorry, I missed this part. Then I think you need to change the definition of bool operator()(valType const& iLeft, valType const& iRight) because it accepts "valType const& iLeft" which is POI reference type, but the parameter you pass in by declaring "std::multiset< ValType * , CompType >" is POI pointer type. You can have a try to change "bool operator()(valType const& iLeft, valType const& iRight)" to "bool operator()(valType const* iLeft, valType const* iRight)". Hopefully this might work. @Ubitso

Comment: I alredy do that. Ty.